# NULL values are excluded from results

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbctemplate, ansi-nulls

One of my code functionality requires user to enter dynamic "WHERE" clause for SQL query.
then this where clause is appended to the sql and executed on MS Sql server using Spring Boot - JDBC Template.
e.g. `SELECT * From Customer_Vehicles where Country in ( 'USA', 'Canada');`
This Code works well if there is  non Null value but it skips rows with NULL values in  country column.

As per MS Sql documentation it skips NULL values as ANSI_NULLS is ON in jdbc connection (default property )..
So I tried to set the property using command "SET ANSI_NULLS OFF" using jdbc template execute method.

```
jdbctemplate.execute ("SET ANSI_NULLS OFF")
jdbctemplate.query("SELECT * From Customer_Vehicles where Country in ( 'USA', 'Canada')");
```

This solution works well for String comparison but it doesn't apply to numeric value such as mileage < 25000
e.g. `SELECT * From Customer_Vehicles where Country in ( 'USA', 'Canada') and mileage < 25000`
doesn't return a row if mileage is NULL.
Same is explained on MS documentation :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Is there a way to include NULL values in the comparison (irrespective of datatype) ?

Note : **users can use ISNULL function , but users are not willing to modify their SET of WHERE clauses used in legacy app.**

Comment: Why not simply write `...OR Country IS NULL` and `...OR mileage IS NULL`? I don't understand the last sentence of your question. But I don't see why someone has to enter this manually. Your application can just add the `OR column IS NULL` conditions in the code, so no one would need to enter this.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): ___WHERE clauses used in legacy app___ Did the same problem with null values **not** occur in the legacy app? I would ask the users to use the [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function.

Comment: Turning off `ANSI_NULLS` is a bad idea. Microsoft plan to remove the feature to turn it off completely at some point; don't rely on such behaviour any more.

Comment: Why shouldn't it skip the null rows. They don't match the condition

Comment: Perhaps  WHERE  ((milage < 25000) OR (milage=NULL)).  not entirely sure.  WHERE milage IS NULL OR milage < 25000

Comment: `SELECT * From Customer_Vehicles where Country in ( 'USA', 'Canada') and (mileage < 25000 or mileage is null)` ?

Comment: "Is there a way to include NULL values in the comparison (irrespective of datatype) ?" - Not in SQL.

Comment: "but users are not willing to modify their SET of WHERE clauses..." -- users do not write SQL queries. Developers do.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing around with `ANSI_NULLS` (which should never be done due to compatibility issues with newer features such as indexed views and `MERGE`), instead just add a condition to your query to include nulls.

```sql
SELECT cv.*
FROM Customer_Vehicles cv
WHERE (cv.Country in ('USA', 'Canada') OR cv.Country IS NULL)
  AND (cv.mileage < 25000 OR cv.mileage IS NULL);
```